# firebase-admin node sdk: Why admin.database is both a function and property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

In firebase-admin [sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/b6edf5a985d022f4bfd0ff144d340c68369f5f3c/test/integration/typescript/src/example.test.ts)
does anyone know how/why `admin.database` can be invoked as both a function `admin.database()` and also a property/namespace i.e `admin.database.ServerValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions can have properties.

```
> function x() {}
undefined
> x
[Function: x]
> x.prop = 1
1
> x
{ [Function: x] prop: 1 }
>
```

Credit goes to Doug Stevenson for pointing it out to me on the firebase slack channel. Thanks Doug!